# Google Map V3 Cakephp helper and multiple markers

Tags: google-maps, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am using the Cakephp Google Map V3 Helper.  I can get the google map to show up but the markers do not.  Here is my view code:

```
    <?php 
echo $this->GoogleMapV3->map();
foreach ($allcondos as $condo) {
    $options = array(
    'lat' => $condo['Unit']['lat'],
    'lng' => $condo['Unit']['lon']
    );
    $this->GoogleMapV3->addMarker($options);
}
?>
```

I know that if I just tell the app to echo out my $condo['Unit']['lat'] or ['lon'] it will do so in the foreach loop (so it is pulling my data).  What I don't know how to do is how to write the code for the $options array.  I have also tried this:

```
    foreach ($allcondos as $condo) {
    $lat=$condo['Unit']['lat'];
    $lon=$condo['Unit']['lon'];
    $options = array(
    'lat' => $lat,
    'lng' => $lon
    );
    $this->GoogleMapV3->addMarker($options);
}
```

How do I write this correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple easy steps to get this to work:

**Download**

Download from https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-google-map-v3-helper and place the GoogleMapV3Helper.php file in /app/view/helper/GoogleMapV3Helper.php.

**Load Helper**

Either modify your appcontroller so that the top of it reads like the following:

```
<?php   
    class AppController extends Contoller{
        public $helpers = array('Html','Javascript','GoogleMapV3');
    }   
?>
```

Or load it in a single controller by adding it to the helpers array as such:

```
<?php   
    class DemoController extends AppContoller{

        function map() {
            $this->helpers[] = 'GoogleMapV3';
            #   rest of your code       
        }
    }   
?
```

**Include Scripts**

Include Jquery in your header. Include the following as well:

```
<?php
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="'.$this->GoogleMapV3->apiUrl().'"></script>';
?>
```

**Create Map Container**

Put this in your view where you want your map to appear. Feel free to modify the properties of the div.

```
<?php echo $this->GoogleMapV3->map(array('div'=>array('id'=>'my_map', 'height'=>'400', 'width'=>'100%'))); ?>
```

Note: you can change the default position of the map by including more options than just 'div':

```
<?php echo $this->GoogleMapV3->map(array('map'=>array(
            'defaultLat' => 40, # only last fallback, use Configure::write('Google.lat', ...); to define own one
            'defaultLng' => -74, # only last fallback, use Configure::write('Google.lng', ...); to define own one
            'defaultZoom' => 5,
        ),'div'=>array('id'=>'my_map', 'height'=>'400', 'width'=>'100%'))); ?>
```

**Add markers**

Can be in a loop or whatever, but this is done in the view after your container is created.

```
<?php  
    $options = array(
    'lat'=>40.770272,
    'lng'=>-73.974037,
        'title' => 'Some title', # optional
        'content' => '<b>HTML</b> Content for the Bubble/InfoWindow' # optional
    );
    $this->GoogleMapV3->addMarker($options);
?>
```

note: only set the 'icon' key in the array if you want to use a custom image. Otherwise, they will not show up.

**Include the script for the markers**

```
<?php echo $this->GoogleMapV3->script() ?>
```

All done!

Alternately, you can use finalize() instead of script() if you do not want to echo the javascript right away, but write it to the buffer for later output in your layout:

```
<?php $this->GoogleMapV3->finalize(); ?>
```

See http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/12/21/googlemapsv3-cakephp-helper/ for details.

Comment: I did, and all it does is add another instance of the default map (well it tries, but since the map is called using 'id' instead of 'class' it only gives me one map...which is what I want).

Comment: Okay do you have `echo $this->GoogleMapV3->script();` in your page somewhere?

Comment: I had taken that out as when I have it in there i get an error message from cake saying "Method GoogleMapV3Helper::script does not exist", although it does loop through it the correct number of times!

Comment: Okay it definitely needs to be in there. Are loading jquery at the top of your page? After you load jquery (using `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>`), load this: `<?php
  echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="'.$this->GoogleMapV3->apiUrl().'"></script>';
 ?>`

Comment: Ok, (already had jquery loaded for other stuff) added the php, now I still get the script does not exist error, PLUS " Method GoogleMapV3Helper::apiUrl does not exist" at top of page.  File called 'google_map_v3.php' is installed at app/views/helper/google_map_v3.php.

Comment: Download it again from https://github.com/swiecki/cakephp-google-map-v3-helper and place GoogleMapV3Helper.php in app/view/helper

Oh and the reason it's on my github account is because I forked it and made a change only to the README so it doesn't get cut off...

Comment: Okay, I just got it to work! Please hold tight, I will update my answer definitively in just a moment.

Comment: Ok, this works sorta.  it takes me to Germany, but if I move it back over to the US I get one marker where it should be (problem is, all 9 results are the exact same address so will have to create test case that is one city over to see if it works still).  The problem is that the bakery at cakephp tells you to stick a file with the wrong name in the wrong folder.  This had a different name and went into lib/cake/view/helper folder.

Comment: Ok, that did it!  Only you have to have the helper be named 'Js' in your controller, not 'Javascript' (I am using cakephp 2.0, not sure if the helper has a different name in previous versions?)  Oh, and BTW, the markers are working if I plug in a different lat and lon.  Thanks!

Comment: Ok. I've updated my answer to show how to change the default position of the map. If you feel I've been helpful, please consider accepting my answer.

Comment: I couldn't have described it any better ;) I might have to update my former post some time.. :) http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/12/21/googlemapsv3-cakephp-helper/

Comment: @mark glad you chimed in!  It would be wonderful if you could update your post (and the instructions over at the cakephp bakery), as a noob like me didn't even know the correct way to name the helper file.  by the way, it works beautifully, so thank you for your hard work!

Comment: Mark, is it fine to pass in defaultlat and defaultlng to the map during the creation of the container as I've done above? Or should those always be set using Config::write?

Comment: sure! that's fine! I just like to keep it DRY - and this means for several places with maps it would be cleaner to set the defaults once in Configs (if they never change, of course).